# PDFBox throwing error: PDPageNode - No Kids found in getAllKids(). Probably a malformed pdf

Tags: pdfbox

Has anyone encountered this error? Did a quick Google and almost nothing came up.

I used MS Excel to print to PDF and I'm getting this error in PDFBox when I'm trying to extract the first page from the PDF file. I can view the PDF file just fine on my Mac using the default Preview.

This is the PDF that is throwing the error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/owoxicr137iaduz/malformed.pdf

Comment: Please supply the pdf in question.

Comment: Supplied in the OP hosted by DropBox

Comment: Ok, at first glance the PDF looks ok. Thus, can you also provide some code to allow reproducing the issue?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I have the same problem with a PDF exported from Word.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide code, but I think you probably closed your document before saving the new one.

Example (not working):

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("..."));
PDDocument newDocument = new PDDocument();

// insert page from document into newDocument

document.close();
newDocument.save(new File("...")); // Causes the error
```

Example (working):

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("..."));
PDDocument newDocument = new PDDocument();

// insert page from document into newDocument

newDocument.save(new File("...")); // No error
document.close();
```